# Is there a desktop application for Jango?

Tags: music, windows

I like [Jango](http://www.jango.com/), but I don't like keeping a browser tab open on it. Is there a Windows desktop application that works with Jango, preferably one that can be minimized to tray?

I'm torn between posting this here and on SuperUser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [JangoDesktop](http://www.jangodesktop.com/install/)

Answer (score 2):

If you were using Linux you could create one in Fogger, that's what I do. You could do something similar like using chrome, firefox or another third party application to create a desktop shortcut, then it would have a separate window, and not just a separate tab.

Comment: the question was regarding a windows application.